# Trying to replicate cofee foam texture in blender with real foam shader

Tags: modeling, rendering

[image]

I'm trying to replicate this foam texture in Blender using the real foam shader add-on.

Problem is, it's not giving me desired outputs, it's giving me more of a soap foam texture rather than a coffee one. Coffee foams towards the edges and are more pronounced on the edges rather than the center, I've played around with the addon but its not still looking right.

Anyone create something similar?

Comment: That's a third-party addon not part of Blender so you'll need to ask the author that one.

Comment: alright, thank you!